# Ray intersections with a set of stable triangles

Tags: graphics, geometry, intersection, hittest

Currently I'm trying to implement a hit test function for a viewing ray to a set of triangles that will never move. I wonder what is the most efficient algorithm or DS to achieve it. Pre computation is ok. I would prefer speed over memory.

I've done some research and found out that Octree could be an option? But what about other? Thanks!

Comment: There is no general answer. It depends a lot on your scene. If the triangles are scattered, a simple grid might be a good idea. If they are compact, then a hierarchy like an octree or an AABB tree could be better. If you want to know for sure, you would need to try all of them.

Comment: For a good balance between pre-computation effort and runtime performance, I'd recommend a KD-tree constructed with the surface area heuristic. This is very commonly used in e.g. ray-tracing.